# How do I embed emoji into Tweepy status text?

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have the following code that allows me type a text on the console that then is sent as a comment to tweets.

How can I embed emojis into this?

For example the emoji code for a smile is "U+1F600". When I add this as an entry as follows on the console:

**"This is a smile U+1F600"**, the literal code is appearing on the tweet on the browser instead of the emoji image.

```
comment = input("[Reply with Comment to tweet:] ")                    
comment_formated="@{0} {1}".format(screen_name,comment)
api.update_status(status = comment_formated, in_reply_to_status_id = id_str)
```

Please how can I change this so that the picture emojis appear on the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy the emoji from other source like [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/) and paste it in console when you want it.
it will not appear as an emoji in the console, but it will appear correctly on twitter.

[image: console image]

**"This is a smile "**

**Alternatively** you can use Bytes directly, for example typing `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81`

you can find all bytes data (UTF-8) for emojis [here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't accept emojis in the format `U+1F600`, what you need to do is replace the `+` with three zeroes `000` and place a backslash `\` before the `U`. Then Python will correctly interpret it as an emoji.

It should now look like `\U0001F600`. Typing this into your console's window will yield an emoji displaying on Twitter.

---

Emoji *can* in some cases also be pasted directly into the console as well, but be aware that not all consoles necessarily support doing this.

Like another answer also describes, you can also directly include the bytes of the emoji, but it's unlikely you'll have those on hand or memorize them.

Comment: tried this before and now gain. The literal value: \U0001F600 is displayed in twitter

Comment: @ibexy: could be that the data is intrepreted as JSON encoded (no further encoding), at which point you'd need to use the JSON syntax, using UTF-16 surrogate pairs.